# How to enable "write" mode through XCUITests for macOS Automation?

Tags: swift, macos, xcuitest

I need a way to enable "write" mode through xcuitests - for example - I’m trying to save screenshots in folder for macosAutomation through xcuitests , but its throwing me “error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 “You don’t have permission to save the file “7C699505-5B6D-4F19-99DC-AF1811E48E2F.jpg” in the folder "screenshot".

Please Refer the code below:

```
let screenImage = app.screenshot().image
    let imageName = UUID.init().uuidString + “.jpeg”
    let path = (self.screenShotPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
      try screenImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)?.write(to: imageURL)
    } catch {
      print(“error”,error)
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to save those screenshots on the host? Is this a simulator or real device?